# CodeIgniter Form Validation - callback not bound to a field

Tags: codeigniter, validation

Is there a way to set a validation callback that is not bound to a particular field, but is necessary to pass validation?

Comment: Like to set a rule that all fields must pass? Can you give an example?

Comment: Well I have a relatively complex dynamic form... I have a section of my form that is populated dynamically to display a persons name, a checkbox, and a corresponding text input. The text inputs are only important if their respective checkbox is checked. In order for the validation to pass, at least one checkbox must be checked and it's text input must have a value. I have created the callback and it works, I just don't know what to bind it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Add a hidden field to your form and</strike> assign the callback to <strike>that</strike> a field. The callback doesn't have to relate to the contents of the <strike>hidden</strike> field.

Edit: Or, for that matter, you could assign the callback to any of your fields along other validation rules. No need for a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can and here is a cruddy example:

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'lang:lang_username', 'required|callback_check_login');
```

Then for the callback:

```
public function check_login($username)
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember');

    $login = $this->users_auth->login($username, $password, $remember);
    if ($login !== TRUE)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_login', $login);
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```